# automise long lists in python

Tags: python, automation

Today I wrote my first program, which is essentially a vocabulary learning program! So naturally I have pretty huge lists of vocabulary and a couple of questions. I created a class with the parameters, one of which is the German vocab and one of which is the Spanish vocab. My first question is: is there anyway to turn all the plain text vocabulary that I copy from an internets vocab list into strings and separate them without adding the " and the commas manually?

And my second question:
I created another list to assign each German vocab to each Spanish vocab and it looks a little bit like that:

```
vocabs = [
        Vocabulary(spanish_word[0], german_word[0])
        Vocabulary(spanish_word[1], german_word[1])
        etc.
]
```

Vocabulary would be the class, spanish_word the first word list and German the other obviously.
But with a lot of vocab that's a lot of work too. Is there anyway to automate the process to add each word from the Spanish word list to the German one? I first tried it with the

```
vocabs = [
    for spanish word in german word 
        Vocabulary(spanish_word[0], german_word[0])
]
```

But that didn't work. Researching on the internet also didn't help much.
Please don't be rude if those are noob questions I'm actually pretty happy that my program is running so well and I would be thankful for all the help to make it better.

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  (1) You get only one question per post.  (2) You have to fully specify your problem.  (3) Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what it is you're looking to do with the result, it appears you're trying to do this:

```
vocabs = [Vocabulary(s, g) for s, g in zip(spanish_word, german_word)]
```

You didn't provide any code or example data around the "turn all the plain text vocabulary [..] into strings and separate them without adding the quotes and the commas manually". There's sure to be a way to do what you need, but you should probably ask a separate question, after first looking for a solution yourself and coming up with a solution. Ask a question if you can't get it to work.

Comment: with the turn plain text into strings i mean, when i copy a list of text from the internet into a list e.g. spanish words = [casa, hola, adios] into spanish words = ["casa,", "hola", "adios"]  It's not like i wasn't looking on my own but it's also not that easy if you don't really know what you're looking for. Thanks for the help though!